# Personal modifications to git submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have cloned a third-party git repo inside a repo managed by me. I haven't added it as a submodule and I have performed quite a few modifications in the code that probably won't be useful to anyone but myself so I dont want to pull request them.

When I try to push my repo, I get a warning saying that I have a nested repo that was not added as a submodule. I know I can delete the `.git` folder of the submodule and that would allow me to push the modifications on the files as if they were just normal files, but don't like the idea of doing it, especially because I am not the code's author.

How should I proceed in this situation? How can I get the changes i've performed on the submodule to be tracked by my repo?

Best,
Lucas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to include some third party into your environment using git alone. The best alternative is probably to [fork](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/GitHub-Contributing-to-a-Project) the third-party module and add it to your super project.

Forking is a practice, to the best of my knowledge, that is proprietary to GitHub. Basically, you get a copy of the original repository that is entirely yours ([ref](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo)). If you can do that on GitHub, go ahead, have it living in your namespace and then add it as a submodule into your super project.

> A fork is a copy of a repository. Forking a repository allows you to
>   freely experiment with changes without affecting the original project.

A few words of advice: when incorporating third-party code in your project, be careful to check for licenses. By forking, take care not to infringe the license agreement you stipulate when adding the third party code into your project. Also, make sure you are ok with any restriction this might pose to your project.

Comment: will test that asap and let you know if it worked but sounds promising

Comment: easier than I've expected. the trick part was only to define the branch upstream.. thanks a lot!